# 10 is evaluating to 1 in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Whenever the user picks 10 in the dropdown (either formData.minRating or formData.maxRating)in main.html it evaluates to 1. I found this out by testing how the ng-change in main.html evaluates. If I pick the formData.maxRating to be 10 and then formData.minRating to be 2, it will say that the minRating is larger than the maxRating which isn't true. But when I do console.log's for all of the variables, it says they're the correct values. So I don't know what's wrong. How do I get the 10 to evaluate to 10 and not 1?

main.html

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center">

  <div>
    <md-input-container>
    <md-label>Set Genre</md-label>
       <md-select ng-model="formData.selectedGenre" ng-change="setGenreId(formData.selectedGenre)" placeholder="Genre">
          <md-option ng-repeat="genre in genreList" value="{{genre.id}}">{{genre.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div>
    <md-input-container>
          <md-label>Set Min Rating</md-label>
          <p style="color:red" ng-show="formData.minRating > formData.maxRating"> Min rating cannot be larger than max rating</p>
           <md-select ng-model="formData.minRating" ng-change="setMinRating(formData.minRating)">
          <md-option ng-repeat="num in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" value="{{num}}">{{num}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div>
    <md-input-container>
      <md-label>Set Max Rating</md-label>
       <md-select ng-model="formData.maxRating" ng-change="setMaxRating(formData.maxRating)">
          <md-option ng-repeat="num in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" value="{{num}}">{{num}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="formData.minRating >= formData.maxRating">Submit</md-button>
  </div>

</div>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('pickMeAmovieApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl',function ($scope,movieFactory,sharedProperties) {

    $scope.genreList = [];
    getGenres();
    $scope.values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11];
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.minRating = sharedProperties.getMinRating();
    $scope.formData.maxRating = sharedProperties.getMaxRating();

    function getGenres(){
        movieFactory.getGenres().then(function(response){
            $scope.genres = response['genres'];
            angular.forEach($scope.genres, function(value) {
                $scope.genreList.push(value);
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.setGenreId = function (genreId){
        sharedProperties.setGenreId(genreId);
        console.log(sharedProperties.getGenreId());
    };

    $scope.setMaxRating = function (rating){
        sharedProperties.setMaxRating(rating);
        //$scope.maxRating = sharedProperties.getMaxRating();
        console.log("max: " + $scope.formData.maxRating);
        console.log("min: " + $scope.formData.minRating);
    };

    $scope.setMinRating = function (rating){
        sharedProperties.setMinRating(rating);
        //$scope.minRating = sharedProperties.getMinRating();
        console.log("min: " + $scope.formData.minRating);
        console.log("max: " + $scope.formData.maxRating);
    };





  });
```

sharedProperties.js

```
angular.module('pickMeAmovieApp')
  .service('sharedProperties', function () {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    var _genreId = null;
    var _minRating = 1;
    var _maxRating = 10;

    this.getGenreId = function () {
        return _genreId;
    };

    this.setGenreId = function(value) {
        _genreId = value;
    };

    this.getMinRating = function() {
        return _minRating; 
    };

    this.setMinRating = function(rating){
        _minRating = rating;
    };

    this.getMaxRating = function(){
        return _maxRating;
    };

    this.setMaxRating = function(rating){
        _maxRating = rating;
    };
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at view source in your browser, then you will see the actual HTML used by the browser.  This might give you some useful information.

Comment: @ComicStix I tried your simplified example here http://plnkr.co/edit/k5Nws7sr98td0yHlmehU?p=preview and everything works fine. Can you please explain how exactly you get the max being less than mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is treating each of the values as strings
you can check by using `typeof formData.maxRating`

In your JS, write:

```
  $scope.parseInt = function(i) {
    return parseInt(i);
  };
```

In your HTML, use:

```
<div>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="parseInt(formData.minRating) >= parseInt(formData.maxRating)">Submit</md-button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Do you know why Angular is treating my array as strings? Did I not initialize an int array correctly?